# Jquery - Datepicker Calculating the days between two dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, datepicker

I am using jquery datepicker and trying to find the days between two dates. However, some dates are not selectable according to my database, so I have some unavailable dates.

What I would like to do is to check the selected date range if they are all available (otherwise give error with div) and then calculate the number of days.

I have come this far;
What I can do is to disable the days on the calendar according to my database if they are booked. But I am not able to get the value(dates from input) outside scope of the code so that I can check if there is any booked day between the date range.

```
<div class="row">
    <!-- Date Picker-->
    <label for="from">From</label>
    <input type="text" id="from" name="from">
    <label for="to">to</label>
    <input type="text" id="to" name="to">
    <!-- /.Date Picker -->
    <div id="combined-dates" style="display:none;">Please select unbooked range..</div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/houses/<%= @house.id %>",
            success: function(schedules) {

                var length = Object.keys(schedules).length


                var array = []
                for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {

                    if (schedules[i].status = " booked ") {
                        array.push(schedules[i].date)

                    }

                }


                $("#from").datepicker({
                    defaultDate: "+1w",
                    changeMonth: true,
                    numberOfMonths: 1,
                    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                    onClose: function(selectedDate) {
                        $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
                        //var selected1 = selectedDate.split("/")
                        //console.log(selected1)
                    },
                    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
                        return [array.indexOf(string) == -1]
                    }
                });
                $("#to").datepicker({
                    defaultDate: "+1w",
                    changeMonth: true,
                    numberOfMonths: 1,
                    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                    onClose: function(selectedDate) {
                        $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
                        //var selected2 = selectedDate.split("/")
                        //console.log(selected2)
                    },
                    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
                        return [array.indexOf(string) == -1]

                    }
                });
                //Non of them works!!
                //var d = $('#from').datepicker().val();
                //var d = $('#from').datepicker('getDate').val();
                //console.log(d);
            }
        });


    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - [**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xqgs9u3y/2/)

You can loop through the date range on select of `to` and validate if any booked date is encountered. Below is the code.

```
$("#to").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
            return [array.indexOf(string) == -1];

        },
        onSelect: function (date) {
            var isValid = true;

            var fromDate = $("#from").datepicker('getDate');
            var toDate = $("#to").datepicker('getDate');
            var bookeDates = [];
            for (var d = new Date(fromDate); d <= toDate; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
                if (array.indexOf(jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', d)) > -1) {
                    isValid = false;
                    bookeDates.push(jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', d));
                }
            }
            if (!isValid) {
                alert('Dates ' + bookeDates.toString() + ' within selected range are already booked');
                $("#to").val("");
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your initial code looks fine as you are getting the booked dates from the database and marking them unavailable on the calendar so the user shouldn't be able to choose them in the first place.

You will need a change function as you select the **To** available date on the calendar it should store them. For the **From** date you should clear the **To** date so it resets the users choice

**Code**

```
var from, to;

$(document).on("change", "#from", function() {

// Reset the To date

  $('#to').datepicker('setDate', null);

});

$(document).on("change", "#to", function() {

// Get the dates

  from = document.getElementById('from').value;
  to   = document.getElementById('to').value;

});
```